# Mitsubishi Canter will not go into 4th gear

Tags: transmission, mitsubishi

2013 Mitsubishi Canter 6500kg GVM 5 speed tip truck.  Recently had a new clutch installed.  Drives fine until the engine warms up.  Then will not go into 4th gear.  All other gears work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The external shift linkage probably had to be removed and reinstalled when the clutch was changed, and may have been re-installed or re-adjusted incorrectly. If that isn't the problem, then there's an internal fault in the gearbox.

The linkage is probably easier to get to, and — if the gearbox worked correctly before the clutch R&R was done — more likely the cause of the problem. I don't think the problem is the clutch itself, as the gearbox can be shifted and the other gears work correctly.

Have a competent mechanic inspect/adjust/repair the linkage. If that doesn't do it, the gearbox will have to be opened up.